# iOS app white screen after first use on some iOS 13+ devices

Tags: ios, xamarin

Some of our users are reporting a white screen when they use our app for the second time. Even if they force close the app and restart, the problem persists.

There are no crashes or exceptions being reported by Apple or our own crash reporting (AppCenter).

Searching online, it seems a few mainstream apps (Dropbox, Spotify) are having this issue too. So far I cannot find any developers mentioning it, nor any leads for what might be causing it.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? It seems to be consistent for certain users, but when we try to reproduce the issue on our own devices we can never experience it.

Comment: Have you tried reproducing this on the prod environment, Like install from AppStore and test until that happens?

Comment: The issue always appears if user didn't allow the network permission when first loading . Does the app work fine on iOS 12.0 and before ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It works fine even on iOS 13. We can't reproduce the problem locally, but we have multiple customers reporting the issue (including a family member of one of our developers however we can't get hold of that device to test). On many other devices we test, there doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Make sure the app has network permission(check it in system setting) .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT yes it does

Comment: @FreakyAli Of course. We can't repro it. But we have many customers reporting the issue including people I know and trust.